# Check whether an integer is a power of 2 without using +,- operations

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, decision-problem, integer

Write a program that checks if the integer is a power of 2.

---

*Sample input:*

```
8
```

*Sample output:*

```
Yes
```

---

*Sample input:*

```
10
```

*Sample output:*

```
No
```

---

**Rules:**

- Don't use `+`,`-` operations.
- Use some sort of input stream to get the number. Input is not supposed to be initially stored in a variable.
- The shortest code (in bytes) wins.

You can use any truthy/falsy response (for instance, `true`/`false`). You may assume that input number is greater than `0`.

Comment: Is it also allowed to output "true" instead of "yes" and "false" instead of "no"?

Comment: Yes, you can use any positive/negative response. Question is updated.

Comment: @gthacoder You may want to clarify input requirements, I'm almost feeling like I'm cheating using a variable with the value to check as input. Is that ok, seeing that GolfScript passes the value on the stack?

Comment: The `pred` function, when applied to an integer n, returns n - 1.  Are functions such as this, which are thin disguises around the forbidden operator, also forbidden?

Comment: @Wayne just like golfscript's `)`, or most c-based languages' `--`.

Comment: Can we output 1 or 0? 'T' or 'F'?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Good point. Input is supposed to be typed by user. Question is updated.

Comment: Requiring the input from a stream automatically penalizes languages such as `AS3` or `Java` which don't have that sort of capability within arm's reach. Allowing "input" variables would level the playing field.

Comment: What is the range of valid input? This is important because a number of answers here break if the input is `0`.

Comment: Don't worry about `0`. Input number is supposed to be greater than `0`. Question is updated.

Comment: @gthacoder Is `--` alowed for C(++)? And unary `-` (negate)? What about negative constants? (`-1`)

Comment: @nightcracker Question is created with idea that you can't use the fact that if `n & (n - 1)` is equal to `0`, then `n` is a power of 2 (reason why `+`, `-` are forbidden). Otherwise, you can use any operators.

Comment: @gthacoder But see my answer, I don't use `+` or `-` and it still works. I do use `-1` though.

Comment: I am not seeing the need for plus or minus so much. It seems pretty easy to do it without.

Comment: Can you use return value instead of explicitly printing?

Comment: It is supposed to be a complete program with input and output.

Comment: If we use `+` in a regex, is that OK?

Comment: @O-I `+` OPERATION is forbidden, so `+` symbol in a regular expression is OK. I found you rewrote your answer without `+` anyway.

Comment: @gthacoder My C answer is smaller than vershov's.

Comment: @nightcracker Yes, you are right. My bad. Sorry. Question is updated.

Comment: @gthacoder Add some bonus for code that works also for 0 (return False). Many answers do not work for this case (should crash if use log, or return wrong answer).

Comment: Can you add Perl 6? It's a separate language to Perl 5, even with confusing name.

Comment: @xfix Good point. They differ fundamentally indeed. Question is updated.

Comment: if -1 as a constant is allowed I can get the javascript down to 28 characters (cannot post, need reputation!)
alert(((a=prompt())&a*-1)>1)

Comment: alert(!((a=prompt())&(a/3))) is also 28 characters and avoids the - sign altogether

Comment: Simple answer:log2 then check if it has numbers under the fp

Comment: Can input be unary?

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the range of valid inputs?

Comment: I know we're 3 years in the future now, but "+/- operators" is non-observable, or at the very least weakly defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### GolfScript, 6 chars, no decrements

```
~.3/&!
```

Here's a solution that doesn't use the `x & (x-1)` method in *any* form.  It uses `x & (x/3)` instead. ;-) Outputs `0` if false, `1` if true.

**Explanation:**

- `~` evals the input string to turn it into a number,
- `.` duplicates it (for the subsequent `&`),
- `3/` divides it by three (truncating down),
- `&` computes the bitwise AND of the divided value with the original, which will be zero if and only if the input is zero or a power of two (i.e. has at most one bit set), and
- `!` logically negates this, mapping zero to one and all other values to zero.

**Notes:**

- Per the clarified rules, [zero is not a valid input](/posts/comments/33451), so this code is OK, even though it outputs `1` if the input is zero.
- If the GolfScript decrement operator `(` is allowed, then the **5-character** solution `~.(&!` [posted by aditsu](/a/17479) is enough.  However, it seems to go against [the spirit of the rules](/posts/comments/33459), if not the letter.
- I came up with the `x & (x/3)` trick years ago on the Fun With Perl mailing list.  (I'm sure I'm not the first to discover it, but I did (re)invent it independently.)  [Here's a link to the original post](http://www.bumppo.net/lists/fun-with-perl/2000/05/msg00065.html), including a proof that it actually works.

Comment: I think it is a bit silly really, golfscript allows one to write the exact solution that the OP wanted to exclude without actually breaking the rules.

Comment: @Tim: OK, here's one without decrements, then. ;)

Comment: how can this work? For example `7/3 = 2 (0010)`, so `7 & 2 = 0111 & 0010 = 0010` which clearly the last bit is not 1

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: No, but the second bit is.  Try doing long division by 3 in binary and it's pretty obvious why this always happens if the dividend has more than one bit set.

Comment: ah I misread this with "divisible by 2"

Comment: I am impressed. It is even shorter now.

Comment: My Pyth `!%lQ1` beats this :) as long as it was invented after the question was posted, which I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 15):

### APL (7)

Yes, that's 7 *bytes*. Assume for the moment that I'm using [IBM codepage 907](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00907z.pdf) instead of Unicode and then each character is a byte :)

```
0=1|2⍟⎕
```

i.e. `0 = mod(log(input(),2),1)`

Comment: Just wondering, what happens if you give it 0 or a negative number?

Comment: @aditsu I don´t know what infinity mod 1 is, but it certainly _shouldn't_ be zero.

Comment: @TimSeguine Mathematica gives me `Indeterminate` when I try that.

Answer (score 7):

## GolfScript, 11 (for 1 (true) and 0 (false))

```
.,{2\?}%?0>
```

Put the number on the stack and then run.

## GolfScript, 22 (for Yes/No)

```
.,{2\?}%?0>'Yes''No'if
```

I love how converting `1`/`0` to `Yes`/`No` takes as much code as the challenge itself :D

Warning: EXTREMELY inefficient ;) It does work fine for numbers up to 10000, but once you get that high you start to notice slight lag.

Explanation:

- `.,`: turns `n` into `n 0..n` (`.` duplicate, `,` 0..n range)
- `{2\?}`: to the power of 2
- `%`: map "power of 2" over "0..n" so it becomes `n [1 2 4 8 16 ...]`
- `?0>`: checks to see if the array contains the number (0 is greater than index)

Comment: 1 byte shorter for Yes/No: `.,{2\?}%?0<'YesNo'3/=`; also I think you're cheating by asking to "Put the number on the stack", you should start with a `~`.

Comment: Fails on 1, which is 2^0

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica 28

```
Numerator[Input[]~Log~2]==1
```

For integer powers of 2, the numerator of the base 2 log will be 1 (meaning that the log is a unit fraction).

Here we modify the function slightly to display the presumed input.
We use `#` in place of `Input[]` and add `&` to define a pure function.
It returns the same answer that would be returned if the user input the number in the above function.

```
    Numerator[#~Log~2] == 1 &[1024]
    Numerator[#~Log~2] == 1 &[17]
```

> True
> False

Testing several numbers at a time.

```
    Numerator[#~Log~2] == 1 &&/@{64,8,7,0}
```

> {True, True, False, False}

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 6 (17 characters)

```
say get.log(2)%%1
```

This program gets a line from STDIN `get` function, calculates logarithm with base 2 on it (`log(2)`), and checks if the result divides by 1 (`%%1`, where `%%` is divides by operator). Not as short as GolfScript solution, but I find this acceptable (GolfScript wins everything anyway), but way faster (even considering that Perl 6 is slow right now).

```
~ $ perl6 -e 'say get.log(2)%%1'
256
True
~ $ perl6 -e 'say get.log(2)%%1'
255
False
```

Comment: The reason that `+` and `-` are forbidden for this challenge, is because if `x & (x - 1)` is equal to `0`, then `x` is a power of 2.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: I see. Interesting trick.

Comment: @ProgramFOX But `x&~(~0*x)` still works. That's only 2 characters longer.

Answer (score 4):

**Octave (<s>15</s> 23)**

EDIT: Updated due to user input requirement;

```
~mod(log2(input('')),1)
```

Lets the user input a value and outputs 1 for true, 0 for false.

Tested in Octave, should work in Matlab also.

Comment: Works in Matlab also :)

Answer (score 4):

### R, <strike>13</strike> 11

Based on the Perl solution. Returns `FALSE` or `TRUE`.

```
!log2(i)%%1
```

The parameter `i` represents the input variable.

An alternative version with user input:

```
!log2(scan())%%1
```

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript, 5

Outputs 1 for true, 0 for false. Based on user3142747's idea:

```
~.(&!
```

Note: `(` is decrement, hopefully it doesn't count as `-` :)
If it does (and the OP's comments suggest that it might), then please refer to [Ilmari Karonen's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17526/7416) instead.
For Y/N output, append `'NY'1/=` at the end (7 more bytes).

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 31

```
print 3>bin(input()).rfind('1')
```

Comment: 31 if you do `bin(input()).rfind('1')<3`

Comment: @Blender Well-spotted.  I'd used `2==` because I figured it should work for nonpositive numbers too.   That's explicitly not required by the rules, so...

Comment: +1.  I was going to post `print bin(input()).count('1')<2` at a total of 31 characters, but it's too similar to yours.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 48

```
main(x){scanf("%i",&x);puts(x&~(x*~0)?"F":"T");}
```

Comment: Can be shorter if unary negate is allowed, is longer if negative constants aren't allowed. Assumes two's complement.

Comment: `*` has higher precedence than binary `&`, you don't need the parens. And if return value is accepted (just asked) `exit(x&x*-1)` would be much shorter.

Comment: There is a `-`: `x*-1`.

Comment: @klingt.net yes, but that's part of a numerical constant. Technically, as it is worded now, only the operator `-` is forbidden.

Comment: Either way, I think you can get away with `~0` instead of `-1` if necessary.

Comment: @Kevin But `~` has a higher presedence than `*`, so the parens are necessary.

Comment: Oh yes, missed that `~`

Comment: That was also my initial idea, but i thougt that every -/+ sign was forbidden. I should read the specification the next time more carefully ;)

Comment: @klingt.net Replaced it with a version that uses no signs.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to to use another approach, based on the [*population count*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) or *sideways sum* of the number (the number of 1-bits).  The idea is that all powers of two have exactly one `1` bit, and no other number does.  I added a JavaScript version because I found it amusing, though it certainly won't win any golfing competition.

#### J, <s>14</s> 15 chars (outputs 0 or 1)

```
1=##~#:".1!:1]1
```

#### JavaScript, 76 chars (outputs true or false)

```js
alert((~~prompt()).toString(2).split("").map(Number).filter(Boolean).length)
```

Comment: This uses addition, which is precluded by the challenge.

Comment: Huh.  I've no idea what I was thinking when I wrote this... I've fixed it now so it actually follows the rules.

Comment: An equivalent JS solution is `n=>n.toString(2).split(1).length==2` for 35 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [Clip](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7

```
!%lnxWO
```

Reads a number from stdin.

Explanation:

To start with, `Z` = `0`, `W` = `2` and `O` = 1. This allows placing of `W` and `O` next to each other, whereas using `2` and `1` would be interpreted as the number 21 without a separating space (an unwanted extra character).
In Clip, the modulo function (`%`) works on non-integers, so, to work out if some value `v` is an integer, you check if `v` mod 1 = 0. Using Clip syntax, this is written as `=0%v1`. However, as booleans are stored as `1` (or anything else) and `0`, checking if something is equal to `0` is just 'not'ing it. For this, Clip has the `!` operator. In my code, `v` is `lnx2`. `x` is an input from stdin, `n` converts a string to a number and `lab` is log base `b` of `a`. The program therefore translates (more readably) to `0 = ((log base 2 of parseInt(readLine)) mod 1)`.

Examples:

```
8
```

outputs

```
1
```

and

```
10
```

outputs

```
0
```

Edit 1: replaced `0`, `1` and `2` with `Z`, `O` and `W`.

Edit 2: replaced `=Z` with `!`.

Also:

## [Pyth](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pyth), 5

Compresses the Clip version even further, as Pyth has Q for already evaluated input and a log2(a) function instead of just general log(a, b).

```
!%lQ1
```

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript (37)**

```
a=prompt();while(a>1)a/=2;alert(a==1)
```

Simple script that just divides by 2 repeatedly and checks the remainder.

Comment: same idea with a `for` loop (also 37 chars) `for(i=prompt();i>1;i/=2){}alert(i==1)`

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica (21)

```
IntegerQ@Log2@Input[]
```

Without input it is a bit shorter

```
IntegerQ@Log2[8]
```

> True

```
IntegerQ@Log2[7]
```

> False

Comment: `⌊#⌋==#&@Log2@Input[]`

Comment: @alephalpha That ends up using 24 bytes for the UTF-8 characters. Another 21-byte program is `Log2@Input[]~Mod~1==0`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Ruby — 17 characters (fourth try)

```
p /.1/!~'%b'%gets
```

My current best is a fusion of @steenslag's answer with my own. Below are my previous attempts.

#### Ruby — 19 characters (third try)

```
p /10*1/!~'%b'%gets
```

#### Ruby — 22 characters (second try)

```
p !('%b'%gets)[/10*1/]
```

#### Ruby — 24 characters (first try)

```
p !!('%b'%gets=~/^10*$/)
```

Comment: there's still a "+" in your program

Comment: I know. :-/ I've asked for clarification whether '+' and '-' are strictly forbidden, or whether they can be used in other contexts besides addition and subtraction. I'm in the process of rewriting regardless.

Comment: Great improvement. It seems like it's the best Ruby result so far. I updated the leaders table in the question text.

Comment: @gthacoder Just combined steenslag's regex with my binary formatting. Definitely can't take all the credit.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, <s>41</s> 40 characters

```
l=Math.log;alert(l(prompt())/l(2)%1==0);
```

How this works: you take the logarithm at base 2 using `l(prompt()) / l(2)`, and if that result modulo 1 is equal to zero, then it is a power of 2.

For example: after taking the logarithm of 8 on base `2`, you get `3`. `3 modulo 1` is equal to 0, so this returns true.

After taking the logarithm of 7 on base 2, you get `2.807354922057604`. `2.807354922057604 modulo 1` is equal to `0.807354922057604`, so this returns false.

Comment: You don't need to cast the input to a number; [`Math.log` will do that already](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2): "Each of the following Math object functions applies the ToNumber abstract operator to each of its arguments..."

Comment: Doesn't it suffer from numerical inaccuracies?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus: I actually don't know. It could be, but I haven't yet encountered an incorrect result.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 35

Works for bytes.

```
alert((+prompt()).toString(2)%9==1)
```

**46 character version**,
Works for 16 bit numbers.

```
x=(+prompt()).toString(2)%99;alert(x==1|x==10)
```

The trick works in most dynamic languages.

**Explanation:** Convert the number to base 2, interpret that string as base 10, do modulo 9 to get the digit sum, which must be 1.

Comment: What about `0x2ff`, which in base 2 is `1111111111`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right, fixed

Comment: so the real thing your doing is checking for modulo 10 without a remainder, but you used 9 to shave a character of your code, `+1`!

Comment: This is kinda cheating but another method: `alert(!(Number.MAX_VALUE%prompt()))`

Answer (score 2):

### K/Kona (<strike>24</strike> 17)

```
d:{(+/(2_vs x))~1
```

Returns 1 if true and 0 if false. Any power of 2 has a single bit equal to 1:

```
2_vs'_(2^'(!10))
(,1
1 0
1 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

(this prints out all the powers of 2 (from 0 to 9) in binary)

So I sum up all the components of the binary expression of `x` and see if it's equal to 1; if yes then `x=2^n`, otherwise nope.

...knew I could make it smaller

Comment: @gthacoder: I made the code smaller, hope you can update you main post to reflect this!

Comment: Doesn't this use addition? And doesn't the question, err, forbid that?

Answer (score 2):

**python 3,   38**

```
print(1==bin(int(input())).count('1'))
```

**python,     32**

However, the code doesn't work in every version.

```
print 1==bin(input()).count('1')
```

Notice that the solution works also for 0 (print False).

Comment: Upvoted because this was my solution as well.

Comment: What if you replace `==` with `&`?

Comment: @SimonT This is not true. Replacing the '==' with '&' will print 1 for every number that has odd number of '1' in its binary representation. Check for example 7=111. There are 3=11 ones. It will return 11&1 = 1.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5.10+, 13 + 1 = 14 chars

```
say!($_&$_/3)
```

Uses the same method [from an old FWP thread](http://www.bumppo.net/lists/fun-with-perl/2000/05/msg00065.html) as [my GolfScript entry](/a/17526).
Prints `1` if the input is a power of two, and an empty line otherwise.

Needs to be run with `perl -nE`; the `n` [costs one extra char](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions), for a total of 14 chars.  Alternatively, here's an **18-character** version that doesn't need the `n`:

```
say!(($_=<>)&$_/3)
```

Answer (score 2):

**C# (54 characters)**

```
 Math.Log(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),2)%1==0?"Y":"N"
```

Comment: The task clearly states that input is not stored in a variable, it should be obtained from an input stream of some kind (like stdin), also, this is [tag:code-golf], try shortening your code a little, at least by removing whitespace

Comment: I think you just mean `Int32`, not `ToInt32`...

Comment: Ya ya. Thanks for pointing out Chris. Earlier it was Convert.ToInt32 and I wanted to change it to Int32.Parse to shorten it. :D

Comment: use `int` instead of `Int32` for 2 fewer characters.

Answer (score 2):

## OCaml - 42 or 45

Since no-one has submitted an OCaml solution, I submit one inspired by nightcrackers C solution.

There is some debate as to whether the operator `-` includes unary negation. Other entries have managed to sidestep the issue by finding a solution that is equally short without unary negation. I instead give two answers:

`let x=read_int()in 0=x land lnot(x* -1);;`

and

`let x=read_int()in 0=x land lnot(x*lnot 0);;`

the `;;` ends a group of statements in the OCaml interpreter and causes the result to be printed as `- : bool = false` or `- : bool = true`, which are clear negative/positive answers as required by the question.

Answer (score 2):

## Rebmu (9 chars)

```
z?MOl2A 1
```

**Test**

```
>> rebmu/args [z?MOl2A 1] 7
== false

>> rebmu/args [z?MOl2A 1] 8 
== true

>> rebmu/args [z?MOl2A 1] 9 
== false
```

[Rebmu](http://rebmu.hostilefork.com/) is a constricted dialect of Rebol. The code is essentially:

```
z? mo l2 a 1  ; zero? mod log-2 input 1
```

**Alternative**

*14 chars—Rebmu does not have a 'mushed' bitwise AND~*

```
z?AND~aTIddA 3
```

In Rebol:

```
zero? a & to-integer a / 3
```

Answer (score 1):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/gtb), 46 bytes

```
2→P`N[@N=Pg;1P^2→P@P>1E90g;2]l;2~"NO"&l;1"YES"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2.7 (<s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>39</s> 37)**

EDIT: Updated due to user input requirement;

```
a=input()
while a>1:a/=2.
print a==1
```

Brute force, try to divide until =1 (success) or <1 (fail)

Comment: `not a%2` can be written as `a%2==0`. Granted, this would be longer in many languages, but not Python.

Comment: @xfix Thanks, tested and updated.

Comment: or even better, `a%2<1`.

Comment: you have a space after `2.` Removing that would save a byte!

Answer (score 1):

## APL (12 for 0/1, 27 for yes/no)

```
≠/A=2*0,ιA←⍞
```

or, if we must output text:

```
3↑(3x≠/A=2*0,ιA←⍞)↓'YESNO '
```

Read in A. Form a vector 0..A, then a vector 2<sup>0</sup>..2<sup>A</sup> (yes, that's way more than necessary), then a vector comparing A with each of those (resulting in a vector of 0's and at most one 1), then xor that (there's no xor operator in APL, but ≠ applied to booleans will act as one.) We now have 0 or 1.

To get YES or NO: multiply the 0 or 1 by 3, drop this number of characters from 'YESNO ', then take the first 3 characters of this.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>33</s>, <s>28</s>, 25

```
p /.1/!~gets.to_i.to_s(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python, 35**

```python
print bin(input()).strip('0')=='b1'
```

Doesn't use not only +/- operations, but any math operations aside from converting to binary form.

Other stuff (interesting, but not for competition):

I have also a **regexp version (61)**:

```python
import re;print re.match(r'^0b10+$',bin(input())) is not None
```

(Love the idea, but import and match function make it too long)

And nice, but boring **bitwise operations version (31)**:

```python
x=input();print x and not x&~-x
```

(yes, it's shorter, but it uses ~-x for decrement which comtains - operation)

Comment: boothby's answers uses the same idea as my first, but is shorter :(

Answer (score 1):

**C, 65 bytes**

```
main(k){scanf("%i",&k);while(k&&!(k%2))k/=2;puts(k==1?"T":"F");}
```

Comment: You can cut off 5 chars by using `main(k){...`, relying on the implicit `int` typing. It might be UB, but this is code golf. NEVER use something like that in production, of course.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (<strike>52</strike> 50)

```
k n=elem n$map(2^)[1..n]
main=interact$show.k.read
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python (33)

```
print int(bin(input())[3:]or 0)<1
```

Comment: `int(bin(input()*2)[3:])<1` also works from the python shell with only 25 chars.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 - 23

```
x=input();print x&x/3<1
```

This is a direct port of the golf-script solution above, that beats the current best python solution by 8 characters. The order of operations works out amazingly well here.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + dc + grep, 24

```
dc -e2o?p|grep -c ^10\*$
```

Reads from stdin.  Outputs "1" if a power of 2 and "0" otherwise:

```
$ dc -e2o?p|grep -c ^10\*$
8
1
$ dc -e2o?p|grep -c ^10\*$
10
0
$
```

---

## Pure Bash (only builtins), 40

```
[[ `read a;printf %o $a` =~ ^[124]0*$ ]]
```

Reads from stdin.  Returns **success** (0) if a power of 2 and **failure** (1) otherwise:

```
$ [[ `read a;printf %o $a` =~ ^[124]0*$ ]]
8
$ echo $?
0
$ [[ `read a;printf %o $a` =~ ^[124]0*$ ]]
10
$ echo $?
1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 124

This is pretty short in Java. Most of the program is just boilerplate code and to read the integer.

```java
class H{public static void main(String[]b){int a=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();System.out.println((a&a/3)<1);}}
```

Comment: I know it's been two years, but you can golf it by 2 bytes by simply using `print` instead of `println`.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 29 bytes

This is a fairly uncreative and basic (no pun intended) answer. 0 is false, 1 is true.

```
INPUT N
A=LOG(N,2)?(0OR A)==A
```

We know that if *n* is a power of 2, then *log2(n)* will be an integer. So, this calculates the base-2 log of `N`, our input number, and checks if it is an integer using the following method.

In SB there are actually two number types, doubles and integers. It also has automatic coercion between doubles and ints depending on the context. When a float is coerced to an int, it simply truncates the fraction and produces an integer which represents the whole part (assuming that number is in the valid integer size–signed 32 bit.) The bitwise OR operator `OR` expects both of its terms to be integers, so it will automatically cast doubles to ints. Thus, `0 OR double` simply produces that double's whole part, which we then check against the original value. If these two are equal, it is a power of two.

Comment: A<<0 is shorter and doesn't need parentheses. And you can maybe use > or < instead of ==

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 47 bytes

(or 21 bytes if input/output can be function argument/return)

```
f 0=0
f 1=1
f n=f$n/2
main=interact$show.f.read
```

Returns `1` for powers of 2, and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Check out our [Haskell golfing rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11935/20260). In particular, just functions are fine, you don't need the last line. (Edit: Actually, this challenge is really old (2014) before functions were default. Maybe stick with the program.)

Comment: @xnor Thanks. I'm aware that this site usually accepts functions as answers, but I was unsure of the rules on function vs full program because the question states "Use some sort of input stream to get the number" and the [other haskell answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17517/12819) does the same.  Also, I didn't realize that this question was so old. Is it considered rude to neco old questions here?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>29,</s>25 bytes

```python
x=input();print x&x*~0==x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19hm5lXUFqioWldUJSZV6JQoVahVWdga1vx/7@hIQA)

using `x&x*~~x/~x` is a modified version of `x&(~x+1)`! Since the later uses `+` had to use `~x` which is equivalent to `-x-1`!

- saved 4 bytes by using `x*~0` instead of `x*~~x/~x`!

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 86 chars

```
function P($a,$c){if($c==$a)return 1;if($c>$a)return 0;return P($a,$c*2);}echo P(x,2);
```

Replace `x` with the number you want to test.

Comment: I'm almost sure this can be shorter, by use of ternary operator... then again, ternary operator in PHP is rather strange, so you may need some parenthesis to enforce precedence.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP (58)**

```
<?php $a=fgets(STDIN);while($a%2==0)$a/=2;echo $a==1?1:0;
```

Simple divide-by-2 loop and remainder check.

Comment: This shaves off few characters `<?php $a=$argv[1];while(!($a%2))$a/=2;echo $a==1?1:0;` Basically `$argv[1]` instead of fgets(STDIN)` and `!($a%2)` instead of `a%2==0`

Answer (score 0):

### ActionScript 3 (63 characters*)

```
var r = Math.log(prompt())/Math.log(2);
return ( (r > 0) && (int(r) == r) );
```

***** I'm going to ignore the fact that AS3 doesn't have a built-in `prompt()` method, (and hope AS3's lack of implementation doesn't get counted against me).

Extra white-space left in for readability and clarity, but not counted, since they can be removed before execution.

Comment: I'm also going to assume that the user didn't enter something funny like `NaN`.

Comment: In my opinion, using functions that don't exist is cheating. Just change this into JavaScript code, and replace `int(r)` with `~~r`.

Comment: @xfix _No!_ I refuse to support the use of an un-typed and classless language! _Bah, humbug!_

Comment: It's not that you use types or classes here. Also, you have definitely too many parens (`return` doesn't need parenthesis, and `&&` has bigger precedence than both parenthesis groups).

Comment: @xfix [Fine, you win](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17456/check-whether-an-integer-is-a-power-of-2-without-using-operations/17507#17507), but may the records show that I still conscientiously object to the use of JavaScript as a serious programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1309), 17

With 1/0

```
`Ar?A>1:A/2→A~A=1
```

With YES/NO (31)

```
`Ar?A>1:A/2→A@A=1$~"YES"#~"NO"&
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (43 characters when compacted, 35 for some browsers)

Readable version:

```
var r = Math.log(prompt()) / Math.LN2;
alert( (r > 0) && (~~r == r) );
```

Compacted version (credit goes to [**FireFly**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3918/firefly) for helping me shave off even more characters):

```
r=Math.log(prompt())/Math.LN2;alert(~~r==r)
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/LFYg7/2/

**EDIT:** On the off chance that you use [FireFox 25+ or any other browser with `Math.log2()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2#Browser_compatibility), only 35 characters are required (thanks to [**xfix**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3103/xfix) for this suggestion):

```
r=Math.log2(prompt());alert(~~r==r)
```

Comment: You can remove the final semicolon and `var`. Also, JavaScript has `Math.log2()` function.

Comment: @xfix Nice, I also used several of your suggestions from the other answer. Thanks!

Comment: I save two characters by removing the `>0`, in which case the function will return `0` or `false`, but my soul is tormented enough by the shortcuts taken in this code anyway.

Comment: @xfix Regarding your edit, there is no `Math.log2()` function yet (or at least it's not standard across all browsers), it's still in the draft stage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Oh, yeah, my mistake. I just prefer to use EcmaScript 6 for my code golf in JavaScript. But yeah, that makes sense - sometimes I mistake ES5 and ES6 stuff.

Comment: You can divide by `Math.LN2` instead of `Math.log(2)`. You can also get rid of the repeated `Math` via `with`:  `with(Math)r=log(prompt())/LN2;alert(r>0&&~~r==r)` (untested, but should work). (Edit: oh, duh, `with(Math)` doesn't win any additional characters..)

Comment: @FireFly Thanks, `LN2` saved me three more characters.

Comment: Oh, I think you can drop `x>0&&` too, since the task specifies "check whether an integer", and `Math.log` takes negative integers to `NaN`, `0` to `-Infinity` and positive integers to positive values, and both `NaN` and `-Infinity` give you `false` for `r == ~~r`.

Comment: @FireFly Dropping that will let through a passed in value of `1`, but should that count as a power of `2`?

Comment: I'd say yes, as `2⁰ = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

## Scheme 40

```
(display(=(mod(/(log(read))(log 2))1)0))
```

It displays `#t` for true and `#f` for false (the booleans in `Scheme`).

For true compatibility you need to add `(import(rnrs))` or `(import(scheme))` (for r7rs) but it works without that in `ikarus` and in most REPLs.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 53

```
perl -pe '$_=unpack"b*",pack"L",$_;s!0!!g;s!111*!no!;s!1!yes!'
```

I can shave off 1 character if i use + in the re, not used for adding.

Comment: Use the `y///` operator for shorter code: `say unpack('b*',pack'l',$_)=~y/1//==1`

Answer (score 0):

**Golfscript (<s>17</s> 14)**

Works from input, using the `base` builtin for binary conversion and counting ones;

```
~2base{1=},,1=
```

Old version, 17 chars, without builtin conversions and without using the decrement operator as a substitute for `-`;

```
~2*:a 1{2*.a<}do=
```

- `~` lifts the input to an integer on the stack
- `2*` multiplies by 2 to solve 2^0 problem
- :a sets the variable a to the number to search for and leaves it on stack
- 1{2*.a<}do sets start value 1 and doubles as long as number<a
- = compares the number to search for with the number generated

Answer (score 0):

## J - <del>17</del> 15 bytes - <del>not . ceiling</del> (0==) . mod 1 . log2 . to_i . read keyboard

Result is 1 for True and 0 for False

```
0=1|2^.".1!:1,1
```

Yes/No version

```
(0=1|2^.".1!:1,1){'No',:'Yes'
```

Comment: Something weird seems to have happened to the title of your answer. You might want to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

### D (83 chars with boilerplate, 17 chars to get the solution)

```
import std.stdio;
void main(){
    int i;
    readf("%d", &i);
    while(!(i%2))i/2;
    writeln(i==1);
}
```

while the number is even divide by 2, when the result is 2 then it was a power of 2

Comment: Um, It says no `-` operation. I see one.

Comment: @Tim not anymore you don't :P

Answer (score 0):

**Perl 69**

```
$_=<>;chomp;$s=1;while($s<$_){$s*=2;$r="Yes" if $s==$_}print $r||"No"
```

Comment: 58: `$_=<>;chomp;++$s;($s*=2)==$_&&($r=Yes)while$s<$_;say$r||No`

Comment: I suppose ++ might count as addition. This is the same length: `$_=<>;chomp;$s=1;($s*=2)==$_&&($r=Yes)while$s<$_;say$r||No`

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5 (36 or 29 bytes)

```
say sprintf('%b',<>)=~/^10*$/?Yes:No
```

If we don't want to strictly output "Yes" or "No", then we can go shorter:

```
say sprintf('%b',<>)=~/^10*$/
```

This second version outputs "1" for true, and "" for false.

Answer (score 0):

### C99 <del>94</del> <del>92</del> 71

```
int main(){int a,i=1;scanf("%d",&a);while(i){if(a==i)return 1;i<<=1;}}
```

#### readable

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, i=1;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    while(i){
        if(a==i) return 1;
        i<<=1;
    }
}
```

#### What it does

<del>It *XORs* the input value with a power of 2, until the bit of variable `i` is shifted out and the value becomes 0. Only if the input value is also a power of 2 (with other words, only one bit in the input was set) the XOR resolves to *zero*.</del>

The input will be compared with a power of 2 value, that is left shifted in every iteration (in other words multiplied by 2) and returns if both are equal, thus the input is also a power of 2.

On success *1* is returned, *0* otherwise.

#### Why C99?

Because the return value of a C program is implicitly defined as 0, if not specified, since C99. Compile with: `gcc -std=c99 ...`

Comment: `!(a^i)` instead of `(a^i)==0`

Comment: Actually, I believe you can just do `if(a==i)`

Answer (score 0):

**autohotkey -45bytes in txt file and 48 bytes with editor and lang.**

```
MsgBox % mod(log(k)/log(2), 1) ? "no" : "yes"
```

Comment: Can't you remove the whitespace? this is [tag:code-golf] after all...

Comment: code golf? it is not. it is autohotkey. thanks for commenting in btw.

Comment: I mean the question is tagged with [tag:code-golf], which means that the entries need to be as short as possible

Comment: You should add a count of the bytes, and use `\n=\n` to make the language and count be bold.

Comment: if i remove spaces the code will break.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 55

```
<? if(fmod(log($argv[1],2),1)==0) echo 1; else echo 0;
```

Eg:

```
# php pow2.php 8
1
# php pow2.php 9
0
```

### PHP w/ interactive I/O, 107

```
<? $h=fopen('php://stdin','r');$n=trim(fgets($h));fclose($h);if(fmod(log($n,2),1)==0) echo 1; else echo 0;
```

Comment: the OP didn't ask you to output "yes" or "no" so you can shave your code down to:
<? echo fmod(log($argv[1],2),1)==0

Comment: @serakfalcon shaved. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (40 char)

```
p=lambda n:n>0and(n<2or n%2<1and p(n/2))
```

Works for negative number also (returning False)

## C (39 chars)

```
p(n){return n>0&&(n<2||n%2<1&&p(n/2));}
```

or with trick, (work on old compilers without optimizing, withoput `return` operator returns last evaluated expression value) (32 chars)

```
p(n){n>0&&(n<2||n%2<1&&p(n/2));}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 143

Thinking binary ( a power of 2 has always only one bit set so the compare with the integer with ionly highest bit set can only return true on powers of 2 (including the ominous 0 :P)

Update: shaved 2 bytes off due to a derp

```
enum P{public static void main(String[]a){int i=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();System.out.print(i==(Integer.highestOneBit(i)*1));}}
```

Ungolfed

```
enum P;
{
    public static void main(String[]a)
    {
        int i = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        System.out.print(i==(Integer.highestOneBit(i)*1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### BASH, 48

```
x=`echo "obase=2;$1"|bc|rev|bc`;echo "$x==1"|bc
```

Takes input as a command line argument and returns 1 for true and 0 for false. You can easily modify it to echo Yes/No, but the bash if-construct makes it much longer.

Comment: 39 characters: ``x=`bc<<<"obase=2;$1"|rev|bc`;bc<<<$x==1``

Comment: No need for `x` at all - 37 bytes: `echo \`bc<<<"obase=2;$1"|rev|bc\`==1|bc`

Answer (score 0):

### ~-~! - 37

```
'=|*;~~==%['&*/~~]*|:'&^==~[@|1|]@|0|
```

I had to improvise with the number input...it's the Unicode value of the character you enter. Teehee.

This uses a recursive /2 solution.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (EcmaScript 6) - 13 Characters

```
f=x=>!(x&x/3)
```

Creates a function `f` that takes a value and returns `true` (or `false`) if it is a power of 2 (or not) and will output the answer to the console.

Based on [Ilmari Karonen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17526/12819) (so I included a few others of my own, below).

EcmaScript 6 can be run on FireFox or [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey) - no other browser/JavaScript engine yet supports EcmaScript 6 arrow functions. If you want to prompt for input then you can call it as an anonymous function (23 characters):

```
(x=>!(x&x/3))(prompt())
```

But it's less characters skip the function bit and just do:

## JavaScript - 19 Characters

```
!((a=prompt())&a/3)
```

Will do the same as above but should run in all browsers and will prompt for input and output to the console (or in SpiderMonkey, you can replace `prompt()` [which doesn't exist as SpiderMonkey is command-line based] with `readline()`).

## JavaScript (EcmaScript 6) - 20 Characters

```
f=x=>x>1?f(x/2):x==1
```

Creates a function `f` and, when called, will output the answer to the console.

## JavaScript - 29 Characters

```
for(a=prompt();a>1;)a/=2;a==1
```

Same as above but will prompt the user for input and output to the console.

## JavaScript - 32 Characters

```
for(a=prompt();!(a%2);)a/=2;a==1
```

## JavaScript - 34 Characters

```
for(a=prompt();a==(a|0);)a/=2;a==1
```

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 13 bytes

```
?[2~0=m]dsmxp
```

Reads input from STDIN.  Input is not explicitly stored in a variable, though it is stored on the stack - not sure if this too much rule-bending.

Successively divides by 2 until a 1 remainder is found.  Since `dc` doesn't have any native concept of [truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey), I'm taking the liberty of defining my own here.  0 means true, any +ve integer means false:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 15 16 17 65535 65536; do dc pow2.dc <<< $i; done
0
0
1
7
0
8
32767
0
$
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch - 24 bytes

Stealing Ilmari's winning GolfScript answer...

```
@cmd/c"set/a!(%1/3^&%1)"
```

[See explanation here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17456/check-whether-an-integer-is-a-power-of-2-without-using-operations#answer-17526).

Answer (score 0):

#### Note: This question is older than Pyth, so this answer is not eligible to win.

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
!%lQ1
```

This is essentially identical to [@marinus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17472/20080)'s APL answer. We take the log base 2 of the input, take it mod 1, and take the logical not.

---

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
!stjQ2
```

This answer converts the input to base 2, removes the first digit, sums the remainder, and takes the logical not.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (23)

```
int(bin(input())[3:])<1
```

Comment: You need a `print` statement in there...

Answer (score 0):

## [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) 33 bytes

```
a=%1%
While a>1
a:=a/2
Send % a=1
```

Input parameters are assigned to variables `1`, then `2`, etc. It means you have to assign it to another variable before using it in math because AHK will think you mean the number 1 and not the variable `1`. It would be slightly shorter still but AHK treats `a/=2` as a `a floor divide by 2` instead of just `a divide by 2` if and only if it is the left-most assignment operation on a line. I'm sure it has its reasons.

---

This is, surprisingly, slightly shorter than the method that uses `log()`:

```
a=%1%
Send % Mod(Log(a)/Log(2),2)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel 19 bytes

```
=MOD(LOG(A1,2),2)=0
```

Nothing magical or tricky. Input is from cell `A1`. Returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
f n=mod(2^n)n<1
main=interact$show.f.read
```

Alternative:

```hs
main=interact$show.(<1).(mod=<<(2^)).read
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkGebm5@iYRSXp5lnY8iVm5iZZ5uZV5JalJhcolKckV@ul6ZXlJqY8v@/KQA)

---

**43 bytes**

```hs
main=interact$show.(1==).until(<2)(/2).read
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJlnm5lXklqUmFyiUpyRX66nYWhrq6lXmleSmaNhY6SpoW@kqVeUmpjy/7@RqRkA). Halves `x` until it's less than `2`, and checks if the result is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.6, 30 bytes

```
from enum import _power_of_two
```

... there's a builtin lurking in the stdlib ...

Answer (score -1):

Python:

```
print 0==int(bin(input())[3:] or 1)
```

Comment: 10 is a false positive

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way: An unsigned number is a power of 2 if only 1 BIT is set: if (!(n&(n-1))). Subtracting 1 inverts all BITs. if n=10000000b (80h/128), n&01111111b=0

```
if (!(n&(n-1)))
  printf("%d is a power of 2", n);
else
 printf("%d is NOT a power of 2", n);

// to get specific power of 2, search from
// right to left for 1st 0 BIT

int pow2(unsigned n) { // is power of 2?
  if (n&(n-1) || n<2) // if not, return 0
  return 0;
  n--;
  for (int i=1; n&1<<i; i++);
  return i; // 2^i
}
```

Comment: using `+` or `-` is not allowed...

Comment: did you even read the spec? you are using both + **and** -

Answer (score -2):

**Basic BASH command**

```
# assume integer is stored in variable QUERY
[ "$[(${QUERY}/2)*2]" = "$QUERY" ] && echo "Is even" || echo "Is odd"
```

Takes advantage of how the shell does integer division, and drops any remainder.

weylin

Comment: "Power of 2" is not the same thing as "even".

Comment: Nuts - you're right. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i=16;
    if(i&(i-1))
        printf("No\n");
    else
        printf("Yes\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use - operation.

Comment: First of all, you use the `-` operator, that's not allowed. Also, the question is a code-golf, so the intension is that you code should be as small as possible, so remove whitespace if possible, and include the language and the character count in your answer.